How can I avoid the run out of memory error when training the custom stable diffusion model?
Experts.
Now I am trying to train the custom LCM-LoRA model with my custom image dataset. I am using runpod gpu cloud service.
I got this error when training my custom LCM-LoRA model.
"torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 900.00MiB. GPU 0 has a total capacity of 23.65GiB of which 659.81 MiB is free. Process 696946 has 23.00 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 21.09 GiB is allocated by Pytorch, and 1.44 GiB is reserved by PyTorch unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation"
I am using 347 custom images to train it.
I tried with 2 RTX-4090 GPU but got the same error.
Do I have to increase the number of gpu or use other gpu type?
How can I deal this error?
Thanks

Welcome Maksim.  Please kindly enter the error as text within your question (instead of posting it as an image).  People with screen readers cannot see your image.  Thank you!
